# Xamarin forms custom view dropdown is not working

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I’m trying to make a custom drop-down in xamarin forms with some bindable properties. I’m having a label and a list view below the label using relative layout so that listview will always below the label and its IsVisible property will be toggled.

I have created a custom view as below:

**Dropdown.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
         x:Class="CustomViewXam.CustomViews.Dropdown">

  <StackLayout>
    <RelativeLayout>

        <Label x:Name="selectedLabel" TextColor="Red" Text="xcx"
                 BackgroundColor="Silver" FontSize="15" 
                 HeightRequest="50"
                 RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint =
                 "{ConstraintExpression
                 Type=RelativeToParent,
                 Property=Width,
                 Factor=0.5,
                 Constant=0}"/>

        <ListView x:Name="listView" BackgroundColor="Black" 

                           RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint =
                 "{ConstraintExpression
                 Type=RelativeToView,
                 ElementName=selectedLabel,
                 Property=Width,
                 Factor=1,
                 Constant=0}"

                           RelativeLayout.YConstraint=
                 "{ConstraintExpression
                 Type=RelativeToView,
                 ElementName=selectedLabel,
                 Property=Height,
                 Factor=1,
                 Constant=0}"
                 >
        </ListView>            
     </RelativeLayout>
   </StackLayout>
 </ContentView>
```

**Dropdown.xaml.cs**

```
 public partial class Dropdown : ContentView
{
    public Dropdown()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
    }

    public string TitleText
    {
        get { return base.GetValue(TitleTextProperty).ToString(); }
        set { base.SetValue(TitleTextProperty, value); }
    }

    private static BindableProperty TitleTextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: "TitleText",
        returnType: typeof(string),
        declaringType: typeof(string),
        defaultValue: "",
        defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
        propertyChanged: TitleTextPropertyChanged);

    private static void TitleTextPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var control = (Dropdown)bindable;
        control.selectedLabel.Text = newValue.ToString();
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create<Dropdown, IEnumerable<object>>(p => p.ItemsSource,
                                                               null, BindingMode.OneWay, null, (bindable, oldValue, newValue) => { ((Dropdown)bindable).LoadItems(newValue); });


    public IEnumerable<object> ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable<object>)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }


    public void LoadItems(IEnumerable<object> tiles)
    {
        try
        {
            var list = tiles;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        { // can throw exceptions if binding upon disposal
        }

    }
}
```

And I'm using this custom view as below in my xaml page

```
  <local:Dropdown TitleText="dssdasd"  ItemsSource="{Binding TitleList}" />
```

Where TitleList is an ObservableCollection in ViewModel

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _titleList;  
    public ObservableCollection<string> TitleList
    {  
        get  
        {  
            return _titleList;  
        }  
        set  
        {  
            if (_titleList!= value)  
            {  
                _titleList= value;  
                NotifyPropertyChanged("TitleList");  
            }  
        }  
    }
```

**Problem:**

The Text is visible on the UI and text is coming properly, but the listview below is empty and data is not coming. **LoadItems** method in Custom dropdown is not getting called even **TitleList** list is updated. Can anyone please guide me whats wrong i'm doing in the above code.

**Note:** I'm having BindingContext set to my view model in my view.

Comment: You should make a custom renderer of [Picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/picker/) instead

Answer (score 1):

> Note: I'm having BindingContext set to my view model in my view.

Do you mean you use the code in your `Dropdown`'s construction method to set it?

```
public Dropdown()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // Try to remove the code below
    BindingContext = this;
}
```

I recommend you to set the `BindingContext` in your page xaml and remove this code in the view:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MyViewModel viewModel = new MyViewModel();
    BindingContext = viewModel;
}
```

In this way the `LoadItems()` will fire at the first time we initialize the `Dropdown`'s `ItemsSource`. But when you want to update the list, `LoadItems()` will not be called. because the instance of the list hasn't been changed. You can try to modify the method like:

```
public void LoadItems(IEnumerable<object> tiles)
{
    try
    {
        var list = tiles;
        listView.ItemsSource = tiles;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    { // can throw exceptions if binding upon disposal
    }

}
```

Moreover if you want to see the listView's data on the view, you should set its `ItemTemplate` for instance:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <Grid>
                <Label Text="{Binding}"/>
            </Grid>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply I tried the above solution and its working. But the custom view which in my case is Dropdown when used in any xaml file the dropdown list is not getting overlap with other views, insted it reserve the space fir the hidden list view below.

Comment: @MayankShrivastava Did the data show in the listView? You can post some screenshots and more details to describe your issue, it help us to understand your problem. Then let's analyze it together.

Comment: @MayankShrivastava Hi, does this workaround solve this post's issue?